# make qt5.3.1 .pro file from Visual Studio 2013 project

Tags: qt, visual-c++, nmake

I wrote a little Qt utility in VS2013. It works fine when running from IDE - even debugging is great. But VS doesn't generate usable exe (error 0xc000007b - "The application was unable start to work correctly", after I've installed all required qt's dll's). 
Is there any way to compile everything and correctly from VS? To make really runnable exe?
Or - How can I write correct pro file for qmake?
I tried to write some. qmake generated from it makefile without any erros, but running VS's nmake it gives a "fatal error: U1077 return code '0x2'".
As I think it is problem with linker - even I wrote for all used modules all required QT += lines.
Can anybody help? I think I'm not alone who met this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Try doing a full rebuild when you create a release .exe

Comment: I tried it many times - doesn't help

Comment: use dependency walker  to look check for missing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

When you get an error like you got it means you have some `dll`s missing. You can only find out what `dll`s are missing using [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

`*.pro` files can be generated from `Visual Studion` using the [Visual Studio Add-in for Qt4](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/vsaddin/qt-vs-addin-1.1.11-opensource.exe) or with [Visual Studio Add-in for Qt5](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/vsaddin/qt-vs-addin-1.2.3-opensource.exe) depending on your `Qt` version.

If you have a `Qt/VS` application you want to deploy, AFAIK the following `dll`s are needed:

- Qt5Core.dll
- Qt5Gui.dll
- Qt5Widgets.dll
- platforms (folder)

  - qminimal.dll
  - qoffscreen.dll
  - qwindows.dll
- icuin52.dll
- icudt52.dll
- icuuc52.dll
- YourApplication.exe

For more information see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html

Comment: I'm using Qt5 but answer is very like: for me it was enough to add needed qt's dll and libEGL.dll, libGLESv2.dll. Computers without qt installed I've not researched for now.

Comment: These `dll`s are for a project which uses Qt and Qt alone for its development. If you use other libraries you must include the rest of the `dll`s for that library. Of course, if you use `QtSql` maybe you should add `Qt5Sql.dll` as well. That is an overview list. If you want the full list, see `DependencyWalker`.